# how to set multiple options for Zend Form Element in Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a form in which im using this element

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'parent', array(
      'label' => 'Parent',
    ));
```

I want to set Multiple Options Which i do usually like this

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'parent', array(
      'label' => 'Parent',
      'multiOptions' => $profileTypes
    ));
```

Where $profileTypes is array

Now how can I do this in Controller?

My code in Controlller is

```
$form->parent->multiOptions($parent);
```

it throws error

> exception 'Zend_Form_Element_Exception' with message 'Method
>   multiOptions does not exist'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**controller file**

```
$profileTypes= array(''=>'Select',
                                '1'=>'test',
                                '2'=>'test',
                                '3'=>'test',
                            );
$objForm->addForm($profileTypes); 
$this->view->objForm = $objForm;
```

**form file**

```
$objparent = $this->formElement('Select', 'parent');
$objparent->addMultiOptions($profileTypes);
```

**view file**

```
<?php echo $this->objForm->parent; ?>
```

try this one for use multiple option in `zend framework`

Comment: Thanks. But after posting this i found the solution. I missed 
$form->parent->multiOptions($parent);
It should be like 
$form->parent->setMultiOptions($parent);